# Ajax Jquery Post Method Fails with Network Error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I got the following error message in firebug. 
"NetworkError: 501 Not Implemented - https://sandbox-api.v.me/wallet/getpurchasedataenc.json"

I searched STack overflow for solution and got to know that the problem is because of Cross-orgin Resource Sharing. I am writing code in Asp.Net. I could not find any solution. Please help me in getting a solution.

```
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "https://sandbox-api.v.me/wallet/getpurchasedataenc.json",
                                method: "POST",
                                dataType: "json",
                                headers: { "x-pay-token": "x:" + Hash, "Accept": "application/jsonp" },
                                params: { 'apikey': 'I2R9LQGZV3KG3K5B44S3' },
                                data: {
                                    'adminid': 'XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com',
                                    'callid': 'XXXXXXXX',
                                    'context': 'ACCOUNT_VERIFICATION'
                                },
                                success: function(data) {
                                    //alert('response data = ' + data);
                                    console.log('Success'); 
                                },
                                failure: function (data) {
                                    console.log('Failure');
                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Network wont allow coss domain ajax if the server is not enabled it. Also you should enable cross domain in your ajax request

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://sandbox-api.v.me/wallet/getpurchasedataenc.json",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: { "x-pay-token": "x:" + Hash, "Accept": "application/jsonp" },
        crossDomain: true,
        params: { 'apikey': 'I2R9LQGZV3KG3K5B44S3' },
        data: {
            'adminid': 'XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com',
            'callid': 'XXXXXXXX',
            'context': 'ACCOUNT_VERIFICATION'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //alert('response data = ' + data);
            console.log('Success');
        },
        failure: function (data) {
            console.log('Failure');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please help me in how to enable it in ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a **params** parameter to [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) Try without it...

Comment: do you have a .json handler in your server?

Comment: Yes .json handler is there in my server.

Comment: what's the change POST verb to be disabled on the server? What's in server log, application log? there should be a record somewhere... Could you debug both sides? 501 means that server does not understand your request... try to use network monitoring tool (like fiddler) to see what exactly is sent to the server...

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to get the payment details. try using `process="intent"` in `v:buy` tag instead. The response will be straight forward.